# Are all fields the field of fractions of an integral domain that is not a field?

Tags: field-theory, examples-counterexamples

A field $F$ is said to be fracfield if there exist a integral domain $R$ which is not a field such that fraction field of $R$ is $F$.  Fields such as $\mathbb Q,$ field of rational functions, number fields etc are fracfields. I was not able to determine if $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$ are fracfields. Are there fields which are not frac fields? Are there a criteria for determining the same?

Comment: Finite fields are not fracton fields of proper  subrings, as a finite integral doman is necessarily a field.

Comment: This is answered in [this math.overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47106/3959).

Comment: **Dupe** of [Is every field the field of fractions for some integral domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415245/is-every-field-the-field-of-fractions-for-some-integral-domain)

Comment: See also [When is a field a nontrivial field of fractions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497256/242) and [``Minimal generating ring" for a field of fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171041/242)

Comment: This would be a good candidate for a *merge*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was raised in [math.overflow in 2010](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47106/3959) (but I cannot tag this as a duplicate of *that*). To prevent it from remaining unanswered, I am posting the answer posted there by [Robin Chapman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/226/robin-chapman)
as a CW.

Every field of characteristic zero is the quotient field of a proper subring which is not a field. A field of characteristic $p\gt 0$ is the quotient field of a proper subring which is not a field if and only if it is not an algebraic extension of its prime field.

For fields of characteristic zero, we know they contain a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$; fields of characteristic $p\gt 0$ that are not algebraic over their prime field contain a subring isomorphic to the polynomial ring $\mathbf{F}_p[x]$. Either one of them has nontrivial [valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)), which can be [extended to the entire field.](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Math8410Ex2.4David.pdf) Because it is a nontrivial valuation, the valuation ring is a proper subring of the field which is not a field, and its field of fractions is the whole field.

On the other hand, an algebraic extension of $\mathbf{F}_p$ has the property that all its subrings are fields, so such a field is not the field of fractions of a subring that is not a field.